# how to write a generic method for adding numbers

Tags: java, generics

I want to define a method to make sums between
different type numbers:

```
<T> void add (T one, T two)
{
    T res = one + two; 
}
```

the above method not work because type erasure convert `T` into `Object`
and thus the + operator is not defined on `Object`...

How can do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You'll have to use a bounded type parameter:

```
public <T extends Number> double add (T one, T two)
{
    return one.doubleValue() + two.doubleValue(); 
}
```

Note that it uses double as return type because that's the primitive numeric type that covers the largest range of values - and one or both parameters could be `double` too. Note that `Number` also has `BigDecimal` and `BigInteger` as subclasses, which can represent values outside the range of `double`. If you want to handle those cases correctly, it would make the method a lot more complex (you'd have to start handling different types differenty).

Comment: Hmm... What about `BigDecimal` and `BigInteger` ?

Comment: @Lukas: good point; but to correctly handle them would complicate the method enormously.

Comment: actually, that is equivalent to `public double add (Number one, Number two)`. the generics has no effect here

Comment: @newacct: you're right; I started out having it return T, but then there way no way to produce a T as result.

Comment: `Long` covers the largest **range** of values, while `Double` covers the largest **domain**. The range `Double` covers is non-monotonic (aka discontinuous), meaning that you use exponents to reach larger values than `Long` will allow, but not all of the intermediate values between any two arbitrary `Double` values. For example, with a `Double` you can reach +/- infinity, but almost none of the values between 2^65 and 2^66 (as a random choice). You should think carefully before using this snippet.

Answer (score 13):

The "simplest" solution I can think of is this (excuse the casting and auto-boxing/unboxing):

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
<T> T add(T one, T two) {
    if (one.getClass() == Integer.class) {
        // With auto-boxing / unboxing
        return (T) (Integer) ((Integer) one + (Integer) two);
    }
    if (one.getClass() == Long.class) {
        // Without auto-boxing / unboxing
        return (T) Long.valueOf(((Long) one).longValue() + 
                                ((Long) two).longValue());
    }

    // ...
}
```

Add as many types you want to support. Optionally, you could handle `null` as well...

Comment: You probably mean return (T) Integer.valueOf(((Integer) one).intValue() + ((Integer) two).intValue())

Comment: Yes, that would be the same, without auto-boxing / unboxing. Thanks for the input. That's more complete now

Comment: Why the casting? Why not use a bounded wild as suggested by Michael Borgwardt?

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to manually create if/else statements because overloading is a sort of polymorphism so the compiler should automatically understand what to do.

Comment: @Hovercraft: true. However, this approach could also add Strings, or Date, etc

Comment: If that's what the original poster wants, then his desires are *bad programming practice* (tm) as it's asking the method to do too much. Java is not a duck typed language.

Comment: @xdevel2000: I think this is as good as it gets with Java generics. They're not as powerful as in C++. See Michael's answer involving doubles for less code...

Comment: @Hovercraft: why? Any expression language implenentation contains such code, to name an example

Comment: +1 for "duck typed", though :D

Answer (score 0):

Look at this discussion on SO: [How to add two java.lang.Numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721390/how-to-add-two-java-lang-numbers)

It's about the same as your problem. Either way, you should not use generics for this, why? Simple: because with generics you couldn't add a Float and a Double, which in general you should be able to do!

Comment: With generics, you can know the resulting type, though...

Comment: Yeah you can, but I feel it requires too much boilerplate code to make it work efficiently.

Comment: That depends on how you use it. With `java.lang.Number`, the boiler-plate code would be outside of the method. With generics, it's inside of the method...

Comment: Yeps, you're right about that. And anyways, it's write once and should work all the time, except when new types of numbers arrive =)

Comment: I guess we'd all be in trouble when there are new types of numbers :)

Answer (score -3):

```
template <class A>
A add (A a, A b)
{
    return (a+b);

}
int main()
{
    int x =10, y =20;
    cout <<"The Integer Addition is " << add(x,y);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is about Java, not C++... ;-)

Comment: According to the tag, the poster is looking for a solution in Java, not in C++.

Comment: Seriously sorry for the blooper

Comment: Well it shows how C++ has more powerful generics than Java. I wish there was no type erasure in Java :-/