# Function to add Numbers and Strings using Generics

Tags: java, generics, lambda

In an interview, I was asked to write a function using `Generics` that adds the numbers and Strings passed to it. The number could be Integer, Double, etc.

If 2 strings are passed to the function, it should append the strings. Finally, the added result should be returned.

I used Lambda as mentioned below.

```
public class WorkAround {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyAdd myAdd = new MyAdd();
        System.out.println("Adding Integers: " + myAdd.add(1, 2, (a,b) -> a+ b));
        System.out.println("Adding Double: " + myAdd.add(1.2, 1.2, (a,b) -> a+ b));
        System.out.println("Adding String: " + myAdd.add("James ", "Bond", (a,b) -> a + b));
    }
}

class MyAdd {
    public <T> T add(T a, T b, BinaryOperator<T> operation) {
        return operation.apply(a, b);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Adding Integers: 3
Adding Double: 2.4
Adding String: James Bond
```

But then, I was asked to achieve the same result with Generics alone. Something like the below code snippet.

```
public class Trial {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyAdd myAdd = new MyAdd();
        System.out.println("Adding Integers: " + myAdd.add(1, 2));
        System.out.println("Adding Double: " + myAdd.add(1.2, 1.2));
        System.out.println("Adding String: " + myAdd.add("James ", "Bond"));
    }
}

class MyAdd {
    public <T> T add(T a, T b) {
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

Obviously, this did not work because of the following.

> The operator + is undefined for the argument type(s) T, T

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7037970/how-to-write-a-generic-method-for-adding-numbers) thread the closet to my question. But that question did not handle Strings. Is there any other way that I might be missing?

Comment: Do you mean to say, this `<T> T add(T a, T b, BinaryOperator<T> operation)` is not generic enough?

Comment: But I have used lambda in that, right?. I was wondering if I could achieve the same result without using lambda.

Comment: maybe you can try to use function overloading

Comment: @rahimli, yeah but if I use FunctionOverloading usage of Generics become redundant.

Comment: yeap why you wouldn't take a shot then ?)

Comment: The interview is over anyway. :-)

Answer (score 0):

We have 2 cases, String or Number. This differentiation should be made.
The following solves the problem.

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class Trial {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyAdd myAdd = new MyAdd();
        System.out.println("Adding Integers: " + myAdd.add(1, 2));
        System.out.println("Adding Double: " + myAdd.add(1.2, 1.2));
        System.out.println("Adding String: " + myAdd.add("James ", "Bond"));
    }
}

class MyAdd {
    public String add(String a, String b) {
        return a + b;
    }

    public <T extends Number> T add(T a, T b){
        return (T) new BigDecimal(a.toString()).add(new BigDecimal(b.toString()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think the same result can't be achieved using Generics alone but could be achieved using either method overloading or using lambdas.