# Operand + for Number in Java

Tags: java, generics

If I have two Object implement Number Interface, is it possible to add them together?

```
public static <T extends Number> T[] prefixSum(T [] arr,T zero){
    int n = arr.length;
    T [] arr2 = (T[]) new Object [n+1];
    arr2[0] = zero;
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
        arr2[i+1] = arr[i] + arr2[i]; // ERROR
    }
    return arr2;
}
```

I got error message at line 6.
How can I write this program generically?

Comment: You can't do that. First you can't have generic arrays. And to add the numbers, you have to unbox the primitives... and to not lose precision, you'd have to use ugly `instanceof` checks. So, I'd say, look for a different solution.

Comment: Related: [How to add two java.lang.Numbers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721390/how-to-add-two-java-lang-numbers)

Comment: @vanza You are wrong of course he can have generic arrays!

Comment: @sotcha, true, I meant can't create generic arrays. The compiler will yell at you (and in the case of his code, spit out a warning).

Answer (score 2):

A few ground rules before we begin:

- Arrays and generics simply **don't mix well.**  You get into a lot of headaches about the ability to store data correctly inside of the array at runtime (i.e. `ArrayStoreException`), and a lot of raw types floating around (your compiler may have emitted a warning about the generic array creation you have up there).

  For that reason, we're going to move to `List`.  It's generic and a lot more flexible.  If you *really* want, you can convert it back.
- Generics **aren't** really necessary here.  You've got an array of `Number`s coming in, with a `Number` as your zero value.  Since any class that extends `Number` **is-a** `Number`, there's no harm in bringing them in.  Conversely, it would bring us *much* unnecessary headache to bring a generic type in.
- Thinking about it logically, the object hierarchy of `Number` is such that everything that could be considered a `Number` is capable of being `Comparable` as well (and luckily we don't *need* that).  But, considering this chart of number types, I don't see any reason to utilize generics.

[image]]

Here's an example of how the code would look without generics, and only with `Number`.  Mind, this is only taking the `intValue`, so all of your numbers will be integer-precise.  If you want the float or double value, then that's possible too.

```
public static List<? extends Number> prefixSum(Number [] arr, Number zero){
    final List<Number> result = new ArrayList<Number>();
    result.add(zero);
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        final Number sum = arr[i].intValue() + result.get(i).intValue();
        result.add(sum);
    }
    return result;
}
```