# What is Java equivalent of C# default(T)

Tags: java, generics

I'm currently working on generic Sum projection for one of my projects. The code is like,

```
public class Sum<T,U extends Number> implements IProject<T,U,U>
{
    @Override
    public U eval(Iterable<T> tList, Function<T,U> property)
    {
        U total;
        for (T t : tList)
        {
            total += property.apply(t);
        }
        return total;
    }
}
```

However there is a little glitch here since I need to initialize the total (obviously to 0). But is there anyway to do it in java like in C# I could use `default(U)`.

Comment: You could not either do `total += property.apply(t);`.

Answer (score 5):

[Generics only exist for reference types anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721546/why-dont-java-generics-support-primitive-types), so this would always be `null`. There also seems to be an implicit assumption that the + operator is defined for `U` - are you sure there aren't more constraints on what `U` can be? Also have you looked at doing `Stream.map` followed by `Stream.reduce`? (I assume you are using Java 8 as you have `Function`)

**EDIT** I think what you are looking for is the monoid pattern. It doesn't exist in Java but you can define it yourself -

```
interface Monoid<T>
{
    T getZero();
    T add(T left, T right);
}
```

And thus your example would become

```
public U eval(Iterable<T> tList, Function<T,U> property, Monoid<U> m)
{
    U initial = m.getZero();
    return StreamSupport.stream(tList.spliterator(), false)
        .map(property)
        .reduce(initial, (uLeft, uRight) -> m.add(uLeft, uRight));
}
```

but that would require changing the signature of `eval`, which might not be possible as I see it's annotated `@Override`.

This approach is extensible to Lists and Strings with Concatenation, Sets with union and Maps where the value is itself a monoid, "adding" all values of a given key, and functions under composition where the "zero" is the identity function.

Answer (score 5):

Java's equivalent to C#'s `default(T)` is `null`, which clearly would not work in your case, because you would get a NullPointerException the first time you tried to add something to your total.

In order to initialize your total you would need a factory method in java, but it still would not work, because:

1. you cannot use `+=` on generics in java.
2. `java.lang.Number` is immutable, so you cannot add anything to it.

You have two options.

***The massively overengineered approach:***

Define a new interface called, say, `MyNumber` which contains an `add` method, and write associated non-immutable numeric classes implementing this interface, so your code would then look like this:

```
@Override
public <T extends MyNumber> T add( T total, Iterable<T> myNumbers )
{
    for( T myNumber : myNumbers )
        total.add( myNumber );
    return total;
}
```

(You would also need to write a factory so that you can create an instance to hold your total without knowing precisely what type it is.)

***The pragmatic approach:***

Write cascaded `if` statements like this:

```
if( number instanceof Integer )
{
    //declare int total
    //loop to sum integers
    //box the total into a Number
}
else if( number instanceof Long )
{
    //declare long total
    //loop to sum longs
    //box the total into a Number
}
...
```

Comment: also look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721390/how-to-add-two-java-lang-numbers