# unable to use an interface with generic extending Number

Tags: java, generics

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    test((a,b)->a+b, 2, 3);
}

private static void test (Op a, int num1, int num2){
    System.out.println(a.op(num1, num2));
}

private static interface Op <T extends Number>{
    public T op(T num1, T num2);
}
```

in the second line i have *bad operand types for binary operator +*. What is it i am supposed to do to make this work ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add two java.lang.Numbers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721390/how-to-add-two-java-lang-numbers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding the type to `Op` in `test` like

```
private static void test(Op<Integer> a, int num1, int num2) {
    System.out.println(a.op(num1, num2));
}
```

Then your code will output `5` (as I think you expected).