# Addition of two generics in Java (cast not working)

Tags: java, generics

I am currently learning about generics in Java, coming from C++ it's quite a difference.
I'd like to a vector addition, in C++, it would look something like this. (I know that this code is not well-written, it's just for a quick example to show what I want to do)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
template <typename T>
class Vect{
    public:
        std::vector<T> vect;
        Vect(std::vector<T> t){vect = t;}
        T index(int i){return vect[i];}
        void print(){
            for(int i = 0; i < vect.size(); ++i){
                std::cout << vect[i] << " ";
            }
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
        void add(Vect<T> other){
            for(int i = 0; i < vect.size(); ++i){
                vect[i] = vect[i]+other.index(i);
            }
        }
};

int main(){
    std::vector<int> p1;
    p1.push_back(1);
    p1.push_back(2);
    p1.push_back(3);
    p1.push_back(4);
    Vect<int> vec1 = Vect<int>(p1);;
    Vect<int> vec2 = Vect<int>(p1);;
    vec1.print();
    vec2.print();
    vec1.add(vec2);
    vec1.print();

    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to do the same with Java but I can't get a way to add two generics T and put the value (a T) in the first vector. I am doing this :

```
public class Vect0<T extends Number> {

    //Attributs
    private T[] _vec;

    //Constructeur
    public Vect0(T[] vec){
        System.out.println("Construction du _vec !");
        _vec = vec;
    }
    //Getter
    public int get_length() {
        return _vec.length;
    }
    //Methodes
    public void print(){
        System.out.print("[");
        for (int i = 0; i < _vec.length; ++i){
            if (i != _vec.length-1) {
                System.out.print(_vec[i] + ", ");
            }
            else {
                System.out.print(_vec[i]);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("]");
    }
    public T index(int i) {
        return _vec[i];
    }
    public void sum(Vect0<T> other) {
        if (other.get_length() == this.get_length()) {
            for(int i = 0; i < this.get_length(); ++i) {
                Double res = (this.index(i).doubleValue() + other.index(i).doubleValue());
                System.out.print(res);
                T t = (T) res;
                _vec[i] =  t;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So it does print a double, but then the casting doesn't work and I get an error :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayStoreException:
>   java.lang.Double  at Vect0.sum(Vect0.java:37)     at
>   Main.main(Main.java:12)

I hope you can help me figure this out.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Is the type you're looking to store the double in a Vect0<Integer>?

Comment: @jzarob Not really, ideally I wanted to add two T t1 and T t2 and store the result in t1 but '+' isn't defined for Number so it won't work. I guess it's because of type erasure and how Java handles generics in comparison to C++ ?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the code below. The explanation of your problem is in the comments.

```
public class TestGenerics {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[] ints = new Integer[] { 1 };
        Double[] doubles = new Double[] { 1.0 };

        // By not telling the compiler which types you're
        // expecting it will not be able to deduce if
        // the usage of the generic methods are going
        // to be ok or not, because the generics notation is
        // erased and is not available at runtime.
        // The only thing you will receive by doing this
        // is a warning telling you that:
        // "Vect0 is a raw type. 
        // References to generic type Vect0<T> should be parameterized"
        Vect0 rawVect0 = new Vect0(ints);
        Vect0 rawVect1 = new Vect0(doubles);

        // This will throw java.lang.ArrayStoreException 
        // because you're trying, at runtime, to cast
        // a Double object to Integer inside your sum method
        // The compiler doesn't have a clue about that so it 
        // will blow at runtime when you try to use it.
        // If you're only working with Integers, than you should not
        // cast the result to double and should always work with intValues
        rawVect0.sum(rawVect1);

        // In Java, when using generics, you should be 
        // explict about your types using the diamond operator
        Vect0<Integer> vect2 = new Vect0<>(ints);
        Vect0<Double> vect3 = new Vect0<>(doubles);

        // Now that you told the compiler what your types are
        // you will receive a compile time error:
        // "The method sum(Vect0<Integer>) in the type Vect0<Integer> 
        // is not applicable for the arguments (Vect0<Double>)"
        vect2.sum(vect3);
    }
}
```

If you read about the ArrayStoreException it will become clearer:

> public class ArrayStoreException extends RuntimeException Thrown to
>   indicate that an attempt has been made to store the wrong type of
>   object into an array of objects. For example, the following code
>   generates an ArrayStoreException:
>
> ```
>  Object x[] = new String[3];
>  x[0] = new Integer(0);
> ```

Whenever dealing with Generic methods you should think that the Producer should use extends and the Consumer should use super - **PECS**. This is a good thing to know. Check out this question: 
[What is PECS (Producer Extends Consumer Super)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super)

One solution to your case, if you really want to be able to add different types of `Number`, is to always work inside the `Vect0` object with one specific type (`Double`). Check out the code below:

```
public class Vect0<T extends Number> {
    // Attributs
    private Double[] _vec;

    // Constructeur
    public Vect0(T[] vec) {
        System.out.println("Construction du _vec !");
        if (vec instanceof Double[]) {
            _vec = (Double[]) Arrays.copyOf(vec, vec.length);
        } else {
            _vec = Arrays.stream(vec).map(Number::doubleValue).toArray(Double[]::new);
        }
    }

    // Getter
    public int get_length() {
        return _vec.length;
    }

    // Methodes
    public void print() {
        System.out.print("[");
        for (int i = 0; i < _vec.length; ++i) {
            if (i != _vec.length - 1) {
                System.out.print(_vec[i] + ", ");
            } else {
                System.out.print(_vec[i]);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("]");
    }

    public Double index(int i) {
        return _vec[i];
    }

    public void sum(Vect0<T> other) {
        if (other.get_length() == this.get_length()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < this.get_length(); ++i) {
                // Now you're only working with Doubles despite of the other object's true type
                _vec[i] = index(i) + other.index(i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And in order to use it, you should reference the objects using the super class `Number`, like this:

```
Vect0<Number> vect2 = new Vect0<>(ints1);
Vect0<Number> vect3 = new Vect0<>(doubles1);
// now it will be able to add two different types without complaining
vect2.sum(vect3);
```

If you want something more elaborate, you could start by checking out this question: [How to add two java.lang.Numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721390/how-to-add-two-java-lang-numbers?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Cheers!

References:

- [Erasure of Generic Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genMethods.html)
- [ArrayStoreException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayStoreException.html)
- [More on PECS](https://howtodoinjava.com/core-java/generics/java-generics-what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super/)

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and answer.
So there is no way to have an attribute T[ ] _vec; ? No matter the type T, my array will contain Doubles ?

Comment: In that case, you will not be able to work with an array T[ ] of any type and try to add doubles to it, except Double[ ]. Because, for instance, there is no way to cast a Double to an Integer directly. And, at runtime, your vector will be of a specific type, like Integer[ ].