# Casting lambda into Function<T, R> fails

Tags: java, generics, lambda

Mapping function is pretty much a copy of standard mapping function:

```
public <R> ObjStack<R> map(Function<T, R> mapping) {
    return ObjStack.of(mapping.apply((T) current), history());
}
```

Where `T` is inherited from class signature `ObjStack<T>`

Using

```
Function<Object, Integer> f = x -> x.hashCode();
```

as argument fails.

`Object` is definitely in scope of `T` and `Integer` shouldn't matter as it's `R` which isn't constrained.

```
 someInstance.map(x -> x + 1)
```

also errors, `someInstance` is of type `ObjStack<Number>`. Data is referenced using type `Object` internally. I'm using and limited to Java 8.

**Edit:**

Error codes:

```
Error: line (7)
java: method map in class ObjStack<T> cannot be applied to given types;
  required: java.util.function.Function<java.lang.Number,R>
  found: java.util.function.Function<java.lang.Object,java.lang.Integer>
  reason: cannot infer type-variable(s) R
    (argument mismatch; java.util.function.Function<java.lang.Object,java.lang.Integer> cannot be converted to java.util.function.Function<java.lang.Number,R>)
Error: line (9)
java: bad operand types for binary operator '+'
  first type:  java.lang.Number
  second type: int
```

Comment: Try `public <R> R map(Function<? super T, ? extends R> mapping) { ... }`.

Comment: `x -> x.hashCode()` shouldn't really fail for a `Function`, could you complete the code with the error that you're getting? On another note `Number` doesn't support `+` operator. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721390/how-to-add-two-java-lang-numbers) for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to provide flexibility regarding the generic signature of the actual `Function` argument you need to specify the appropriate upper and lower bounds for the parameter type:

```
public <R> R map(Function<? super T, ? extends R> mapping) {
    // code
}
```

Without those bounds the `Function` implementation would have to match `T` and `R` exactly. With those bounds the `Function` implementation can match `T` or use any supertype of `T` and match `R` or use any subtype of `R`. The reason the first generic parameter uses `super` and the second generic parameter uses `extends` is because the `Function` *consumes* an object of type `T` and *produces* an object of type `R`—see [What is PECS (Producer Extends Consumer Super)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super).

---

Regarding:

> ```
> someInstance.map(x -> x + 1)
> ```

If `someInstance` is a `ObjStack<Number>` then `x` is a `Number` in that `Function`. In other words, you've created a `Function<Number, ???>` (where I put `???` because I don't know if the return type is supposed to be `Number` or, for instance, `Integer`). In Java, objects of type `Number` cannot be used with mathamatical operators (i.e. `+`). You'll need to convert `x` to an appropriate type, for instance:

```
someInstance.map(x -> x.intValue() + 1);
```

Comment: `x -> x.hashCode()` should work with OP's signature as well.

Comment: Yes, but `Function<Object, Integer> f = x -> x.hashCode()` would not work with the OP's current signature; they wouldn't be able to pass `f` directly without the `? super T` bounds.

Comment: Depends really how its initialised. This `ObjStack<Object> someInstance = new ObjStack<>();
        someInstance.map(x -> x.hashCode());` would work still.

Comment: Yes, that would work. But the OP appears to be using something akin to `Function<Object, Integer> f = x -> x.hashCode(); ObjStack<Number> someInstance = new ObjStack<>(); someInstance.map(f);`. As a matter of course one should default to using upper/lower bounded wildcards anyway, unless there's a good reason not to.