# Adding a List Java.Lang.Numbers

Tags: java-8

I have a list that has to accept either a list of Integer/Double/Float/Long and return the sum.
I tried this

```
public static Number getSum(List< ? extends Number> lst) {
    return lst.stream().reduce(0.0, (a, b) -> a+b);
}
```

But I am getting this error in compile time

```
The operator + is undefined for the argument type(s) capture#3-of ? extends java.lang.Number, capture#3-of ? extends java.lang.Number
```

Comment: You cant add two Numbers without knowing if they are integer, long, or double etc. If they are all real numbers, use doubleValue()

Comment: You can try to use reflection in order to get the static `sum` method. You can then call it using the parameters. However, this only works if both have the same type and the type has the `sum` method.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add two java.lang.Numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721390/how-to-add-two-java-lang-numbers)

Answer (score 0):

There can be a custom subclass of Number, that cannot be applied to `+`.
E.g. you declared a class Natural

```java
class Natural extends Number {
    ...
}
```

You can't add it using plus operator.

So I think the best you can to is to cast them to `double` first.

```java
public static Number getSum(List< ? extends Number> lst) {
    return lst.stream().mapToDouble(Number::doubleValue).sum();
}
```